# Video outside the viewport - but not really?

Tags: google-search-console

I'm getting a `Video outside the viewport` error for one of my pages in the Google Search Console. This error is preventing the video from being indexed. However, the video shows entirely within the screen (See pic below) although you have to scroll down to reach it.

What could be a reason why Google thinks the video is outside the viewport? It's there a definition for the viewport other than the screen?

[image]

Comment: It seems to be fine on windows brave and mobile brave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just run into this problem too. This page explains the error https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9495631#indexing_status

*The video must appear **in the viewport when loading the page** to be considered for indexing. Move the video so that the entire video is inside the renderable area of the page and seen when the page loads.*

So its because you need to scroll down the page to view your video. If you want it to be indexed you'll need to move it to the top of your page so that its visible on initial page load.